# just_audio plugin is giving MissingPluginException for Flutter windows application

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to play audio file from asset using just_audio plugin with latest version. When I try to set the audio source it is giving the following error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGhcF.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGhcF.png)

The plugin documentation clearly shows that it supports windows platform then why it is giving this missing plugin exception.

This is my piece of code:

```html
playAudio()
{
  final player = AudioPlayer();
 await player.setAsset('sound/tone.mp3');
 player.play();
 
}
```

This is my asset file declaration in pubspec.yaml file

```html
 assets:
    - img/
    - sound/tone.mp3
```

Any could help me to solve this issue please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the `just_audio_libwinmedia` dependency to pubspec.yaml?

The [document](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) says need this dependency too.

> Add the just_audio_libwinmedia dependency to your pubspec.yaml alongside just_audio: